# PDO - SQLSTATE[42000] error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert-update

I'm attempting to cut down on the amount of PHP code needed to insert a lot of different $_POST data into a database. I'm currently using PDO with named params and listing them out manually every time. Perhaps there is a cleaner/better way than I'm attempting with my example, however, I'm in a position where I can't refactor the 100's of captured variables I already have listed like this:

```
$digital_fee = (isset ($_POST['digital_fee']) ? $_POST['digital_fee'] : '');    
$banner_1 = (isset ($_POST['banner_1']) ? 1 : 0);
```

And the remaining PHP - SQL is written out like this:

```
$statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table
                            (digital_fee, banner_1)
                            VALUES
                            (:digital_fee, :banner_1)
                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                            digital_fee=:digital_fee, banner_1=:banner_1");

$statement->bindParam(':arn_mkt_stn', $arn_mkt_stn);
$statement->bindParam(':digital_fee', $digital_fee);

$statement->execute();
```

So I'm testing something like the below which I thought to turn into a Class/Function and call it passing in existing assoc arrays e.g. myFunction($db, $table, $arr_digital);

```
// example function to handle the PDO named params db inserts

$digital_fee ='500';
$banner_1 = '0';

$arr_digital = array("digital_fee"=>$digital_fee, "banner_1"=>$banner_1);   
$table = 'myTable';

//create sql string with $vars
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (";  
foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
    $sql.= "$key, ";    
}

$sql.= ") VALUES ( ";
foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
    $sql.= ":$key, ";
}

$sql.= ") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";    
foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){ 
    $sql.= "$key=:$key, ";  
}   
echo $sql;

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);


$statement->bindParam(':arn_mkt_stn', $arn_mkt_stn);
foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
         $statement->bindParam(":$key, $val");
}

$statement->execute();
```

Running this returns an error which I think is format related (hopefully) - here's the message,
Any pointers gratefully received and sorry this is a long post.

```
Fatal error:
  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
    'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
     You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
     ') VALUES ( '500', '0', ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE digital_fee='500', banner_1='0'' at line 1'
```

rich.

Comment: whats the full sql statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $digital_fee ='500';
    $banner_1 = '0';

    $arr_digital = array("digital_fee"=>$digital_fee, "banner_1"=>$banner_1);   
    $table = 'myTable';

    //create sql string with $vars
    foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
        $columns[]= $key;  
        $vals [] = ':'.$key;
        $updates[]= "$key = :$key";

    }
    $column = implode(', ', $columns);
    $values = implode(', ', $vals);
    $update = implode(', ', $updates);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $table ($column) VALUES ($values) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE $update";  
    echo $sql;

    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);


    $statement->bindParam(':arn_mkt_stn', $arn_mkt_stn);
    foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
            $statement->bindParam(":$key", $val);
    }

    $statement->execute();
```

Try now ..  should do fine not tested

Comment: Surace, Also awesome! - I really like the cleaner structure. Insert works, however only inserting last $val '0' in digital_fee & banner_1. $arn_mkt_stn is unique. I tried putting that at the start of the array, but the insert isn't recognizing it - perhaps the Statment->bindParam loop is only keeping the last array value? (I'm a newbie to php ;-) thanks!

Comment: Surace, I'm thinking perhaps I need to 'accumulate' the Statment->bindParam() method calls in the object somehow before executing? - Thanks- R

Comment: OK Found the issue- quite small, need to use bindValue `code` foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
            $statement->bindValue(":$key", $val);
    }`code`
Instead of bindParam which works by binding to a variable, and I'm  re-using the variable $val... thanks again guys!

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL statement. You're always adding a comma, even when it's not needed. Try something like this:

```
$comma = "";
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (";  
foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
    $sql.= $comma . "$key ";    
    $comma = ","
}

$comma = "";
$sql.= ") VALUES ( ";
foreach ($arr_digital as $key => $val){
    $sql.= $comma . ":$key ";
    $comma = ","
}
```

That will add nothing on the first run through, but subsequent iterations will add a comma before the variable.

Comment: Thanks andrewsi - Didn't think of working with the $comma that way. Tested it and works well- cheers!

Comment: I can't take the credit for it myself - I saw someone else do it that way on Stackoverflow a month or so back, and thought it was much more elegant than what I'd been doing before...